# Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices

Tags: api, maps

I don't know why Wen run the android app i'm developing, when i want to show maps i obtain an acivity blank with only zoom buttons and the log is:

```
 Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
```

This is the activity that show the map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

This is the file manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="md.clt.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="md.client.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="md.client.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!--  Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
<uses-permission      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Allows the API to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<!-- Google Maps Android API requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My_apy_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="md.clt.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="md.clt.android.PoiMap"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_poi_map" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="md.clt.android.PoiListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_poi_list" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

What it means?